# Udev Substitution for ACTION?

Tags: linux, kernel, udev

According to the udev man pages, `%k` returns the kernel name for the device and `%n` returns the kernel number for the device.  Is there no substitution for action?

`KERNEL=="sda"` <===== `%k` would provide sda
`KERNEL=="sda3"` <===== `%n` would provide sda3
`ACTION=="add"` <===== ????????

Comment: It doesn't look like it. But there are only two different actions. You could write slightly different rules to match each value of `ACTION`.

Comment: I just used "add" and "remove" as arguments in my RUN+='script'.